# Using $.getJSON to send data in specific format?

Tags: ajax

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/site/ajax/checkusername',
    {username: $('#username').val()},
    function(data) 
    {
        if (data == "TRUE") 
        {
            $("#available").text("This username is available!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $("#available").text("This username is not available!");
        }
    }
    );
```

returns a request url of:

```
http://my.local/site/ajax/checkusername?username=sdfsdf
```

I would like it to return in the form:

```
http://my.local/site/ajax/checkusername/username/sdfsdf
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: By creating the whole URL yourself instead of passing in `username` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/site/ajax/checkusername/username/' + encodeURIComponent($('#username').val()),
    function(data) 
    {
        if (data == "TRUE") 
        {
            $("#available").text("This username is available!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $("#available").text("This username is not available!");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: To be correct in theory as well as in practice you also need a call to `encodeURIComponent`; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/332872/50079