# JQuery UI autocomplete with Zend Framework Request URL issues?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am using:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: "http://ztest.local/ajax/ac"
    });
```

So if a user types in the search box, a request is sent to the server...problem is I would like the format to be of the form:

```
http://ztest.local/ajax/ac/term/foo
```

However the request is given as:

```
http://ztest.local/ajax/ac?term=foo
```

I have tried:

```
source: 'http://ztest.local/ajax/ac/term/' + encodeURIComponent($('#search').val()
```

however that didn't even make a request...

Not sure how to move forward, [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978917/using-getjson-to-send-data-in-specific-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used JQuery-Autocomplete with Zend for a project couple of months ago. Here is how I wrote up the source, hope it helps.

```
 $( "#unit_autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {     
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/becasPropias/public/unit/autocomplete/format/json'+
                     '/type/'+type+'/term/'+request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( data ) {
                    $("#unit_autocomplete").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    $("#unit_autocomplete").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                } 
            });
        },
        minLength:2,
        select: function(event, selectedItem) {
            toggle('hidden_unit', selectedItem['item']);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

Out of this whole code, here is the part that interests you:

```
source: function( request, response ) {     
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/becasPropias/public/unit/autocomplete/format/json'+
                     '/type/'+type+'/term/'+request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function( data ) {
                    $("#unit_autocomplete").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    $("#unit_autocomplete").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                } 
            });
        }
```

And out of this code

```
    url: 'http://localhost/becasPropias/public/unit/autocomplete/format/json'+
                     '/type/'+type+'/term/'+request.term,
```

As you see, you can put in the url as you need. The code for this is available in my [git account](https://github.com/joyjowy/TFG/blob/master/public/js/pick-unit-autocomplete.js).